# Simple http reverse-proxying using Traefik always yields 404

Tags: traefik

I started Traefik using the prebuilt binary (v1.6.4) with the following command:

```
./traefik_linux-amd64 --configFile=traefik.toml
```

traefik.toml file:

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":11111"

[backends]
  [backends.abcd]
    [backends.abcd.servers]
      [backends.abcd.servers.server0]
        url = "http://10.0.3.192:80"

[frontends]
  [frontends.frontend1]
    backend = "abcd"
    [frontends.frontend1.routes.abcd]
      rule = "Path:/abcd"
```

curl http://localhost:11111/abcd -v

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 11111 (#0)
> GET /abcd HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:11111
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Date: Mon, 25 Jun 2018 02:00:27 GMT
< Content-Length: 19
< 
404 page not found
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

A service is running at http://10.0.3.192:80 (inside an lxc container) and if I curl directly:
curl http://10.0.3.192 -v

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://10.0.3.192/
*   Trying 10.0.3.192...
* Connected to 10.0.3.192 (10.0.3.192) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.0.3.192
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 25 Jun 2018 01:58:12 GMT
< Content-Length: 34
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< 
* Connection #0 to host 10.0.3.192 left intact
<snip / garbage out>
```

Anything I should have done differently on the config file?

EDIT: Solved. See comments.

Comment: Ok it seems like I need to add file [file] before [backends]. Even with that, there's still still an issue with trailing slash (/abcd and /abcd/ treated differently) and I'm still only getting 301 instead of 200.

Comment: I got it working now. The backend service must also be serving the same path (/abcd). I initially already had it that way, but changed it in a misguided attempt to fix my initial error (lack of [file]).